# check if there is Exactly the same image as input image

Tags: python, compare, subtraction

I want to know How can i Find an image  in Massive data (there are a lot of images in a Folder) and i want to Find image which is ***Exactly*** the same as input image (Given an input image from another folder not in the data folder ) and Compare the input image with all of the massive data , if it found Exactly The Same Image ,then show its name as output(the name of the Same Image in Folder,Not input name) (**for example: dafs.jpg**)

using python

I am thinking about comparing the exact value of RGB pixels and Subtract the pixel of input image from each of the images in the folder

but i don't know how to do that in python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Comparing RGB Pixel Values

You could use the [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module to get access to the pixel data of a particular image. Keep in mind that `pillow` supports [these image formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#fully-supported-formats).

If we make a few assumptions about what it means for 2 images to be identical, based on your description, both images must:

- Have the same dimensions (height and width)
- Have the same RGB pixel values (the RGB values of pixel [x, y] in the input image must be the same as the RGB values of pixel [x, y] in the output image)
- Be of the same orientation (related to the previous assumption, an image is considered to be not identical compared to the same image rotated by 90 degrees)

then if we have 2 images using the `pillow` module

```python
from PIL import Image

original = Image.open("input.jpg")
possible_duplicate = Image.open("output.jpg")
```

the following code would be able to compare the 2 images to see if they were identical

```python
def compare_images(input_image, output_image):
  # compare image dimensions (assumption 1)
  if input_image.size != output_image.size:
    return False

  rows, cols = input_image.size

  # compare image pixels (assumption 2 and 3)
  for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
      input_pixel = input_image.getpixel((row, col))
      output_pixel = output_image.getpixel((row, col))
      if input_pixel != output_pixel:
        return False

  return True
```

by calling

```python
compare_images(original, possible_duplicate)
```

Using this function, we could go through a set of images

```python
from PIL import Image

def find_duplicate_image(input_image, output_images):
  # only open the input image once
  input_image = Image.open(input_image)

  for image in output_images:
    if compare_images(input_image, Image.open(image)):
      return image
```

Putting it all together, we could simply call

```python
original = "input.jpg"
possible_duplicates = ["output.jpg", "output2.jpg", ...]

duplicate = find_duplicate_image(original, possible_duplicates)
```

Note that the above implementation will only find the *first* duplicate, and return that. If no duplicate is found, `None` will be returned.

One thing to keep in mind is that performing a comparison on every pixel like this can be costly. I used [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Sierpinski_square.jpg) and ran `compare_images` using this as the input and the output 100 times using the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html) module, and took the average of all those runs

```python
num_trials = 100
trials = timeit.repeat(
    repeat=num_trials,
    number=1,
    stmt="compare_images(Image.open('input.jpg'), Image.open('input.jpg'))",
    setup="from __main__ import compare_images; from PIL import Image"
)
avg = sum(trials) / num_trials

print("Average time taken per comparison was:", avg, "seconds")

# Average time taken per comparison was 1.3337286046380177 seconds
```

Note that this was done on an image that was only 600 by 600 pixels. If you did this with a "massive" set of possible duplicate images, where I will take "massive" to mean at least 1M images of similar dimensions, this could possibly take ~15 days (1,000,000 * 1.28s / 60 seconds / 60 minutes / 24 hours) to go through and compare each output image to the input, which is not ideal.

Also keep in mind that these metrics will vary based on the machine and operating system you are using. The numbers I provided are more for illustrative purposes.

#### Alternative Implementation

While I haven't fully explored this implementation myself, one method you could try would be to precompute a hash value of the pixel data of each of your images in your collection using a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). If you stored these in a database, with each hash containing a link to the original image or image name, then all you would have to do is calculate the hash of the input image using the same hashing function and compare the hashes instead. This would same lots of computation time, and would make a much more efficient algorithm.

[This blog post](https://blog.iconfinder.com/detecting-duplicate-images-using-python-cb240b05a3b6) describes one implementation for doing this.

### Update - 2018-08-06

As per the request of the OP, if you were given the directory of the possible duplicate images and not the explicit image paths themselves, then you could use the `os` and `ntpath` modules like so

```python
import ntpath
import os

def get_all_images(directory):
  image_paths = []

  for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    # to be as careful as possible, you might check to make sure that
    # the file is in fact an image, for instance using
    # filename.endswith(".jpg") to check for .jpg files for instance
    image_paths.append("{}/{}".format(directory, filename))

  return image_paths

def get_filename(path):
  return ntpath.basename(path)
```

Using these functions, the updated program might look like

```python
possible_duplicates = get_all_images("/path/to/images")
duplicate_path = find_duplicate_image("/path/to/input.jpg", possible_duplicates)
if duplicate_path:
  print(get_filename(duplicate_path))
```

The above will only print the name of the duplicate image if there was a duplicate, otherwise, it will print nothing.

Comment: Hi Harry
THX for ur answer

I just want to Compare 3*4 images with max size dpi 300
but my problem is ""  I don't want to name each of images in the folder like u did ( possible_duplicates = ["output.jpg", "output2.jpg", ...])   ""   Instead 
I just want to say this is the address of folder (EX: D:\AI\DeepLizard) and then it try to find the similar one and give it's name back to me (EX: D:\AI\DeepLizard\Apple.jpg  ====>>> Apple.jpg)

Comment: But i don't know how to do that
Would u plz help me on that?!

but u know its not the general one because u should have the data before and u must have hash them already 

but i don't have such thing

Comment: Thank u 
wish u the best